# CasperJs download() can't download the mp4 file

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to download from a website which have mp4 video link provided in video tag. After getting video link from website i tried to download it using following Code.

```
casper.download(videolink,fileName);
```

but it output 0mb file on my directory. Any Solution??

Comment: What CasperJs/Phantomjs version are you using? What is the log output of your script? Is there enough disk space to save a file? (sorry for asking this, but we have to eliminate even the most dumb reason of an error). Is the videofile stored at the same host as the site or at a videohosting service like Wistia or Vimeo?

Comment: Sorry for late reply.
CasperJs Version 1.1.0-beta3. Log output is fine no logs are showing there. yes image size is 1.3mb and space available is 42gb. yes it is stored in same host

Comment: "No logs are showing there" (did you mean errors?) Have you turned on debugging output and customized useragent string in page settings? What version is PhantomJS? Is the link correct? (I noticed Casper doesn't identify error on denied/failed download). Also, while the 42Gb space is a lot, does your script have permission to write to its saving directory?